# Arquivo batch para criar outro arquivo batch

Tags: cmd, batch

É possível que um arquivo batch (EXEMPLO1.bat) crie outro arquivo batch (EXEMPLO2.bat) já programado? Onde eu determino a programação do EXEMPLO2.bat dentro do EXEMPLO1.bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, basta colocar os comandos depois do `echo` e utilizar o símbolo `>` para especificar qual será o nome do arquivo que deseja criar.

É possível especificar qualquer extensão, o conteúdo sempre será gravado em texto plano.

Utilizando apenas um simbolo `>` o comando irá sobrescrever o conteúdo do arquivo especificado em seguida.

Utilizando dois símbolos `>>` o comando adiciona uma linha no final do arquivo especificado em seguida. Deve utilizar esse se for gravar mais de um comando no mesmo arquivo.

Esse comando abaixo cria um outro arquivo com o comando de abrir o bloco de notas:

```
@echo off
echo START NOTEPAD.EXE >> abre_notepad.bat
echo Arquivo criado.
pause > nul
```